# Restrict listView Items from duplicating

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem dealing with the duplication of my `ListView`. As you can see on the screenshot, I have a `spinner` that contains all of the items needed. when the user clicks that specific item, it will add on my `ListView`. but the problem is the data being duplicated.

This is the Image:

[image]

**SCENARIO:**
pretend this is the list items

A

B

C

D

If I click "A". It will add on my `ListView` right?. and click "B". so the data on my `ListView` is: A and B. If I click again "A", It will add which it has the current Item on my `ListView`. I need to restrict the duplication that is happening right now.

This is the code when I click my `Spinner`

```
 public void addViolationListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner_violation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent2, View view, int position2, long id) {

            if (position2 != 0) {

                vio_val = String.valueOf(spinner_violation.getSelectedItem());
                adapter = new ViolationAdapter(getContext(), generateData());

                lv_inspector_violation.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

this is the `generateData()`

```
private ArrayList<InspectorViolationItem> generateData() {
    items.add(new InspectorViolationItem(emp_val, vio_val));
    HashSet<InspectorViolationItem> hs = new HashSet<>();
    hs.addAll(items);
    items.clear();
    items.addAll(hs);
    return items;
}
```

the `InspectorViolationItem` is just a `Getters` and `Setters` so I think that don't need to post the code.

And lastly, This the Adapter that I've used:

```
public class ViolationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InspectorViolationItem> {

Context c;

private ArrayList<InspectorViolationItem> itemsArrayList;


public ViolationAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<InspectorViolationItem> itemsArrayList) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_violation, itemsArrayList);
    this.c = context;
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;

}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // 1. Create inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // 2. Get rowView from inflater
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_violation, parent, false);

    // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
    TextView labelView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_violation_employee);
    TextView valueView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_violation_violation);



    // 4. Set the text for textView
    labelView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getEmployee());
    valueView.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getViolation());

    // 5. retrn rowView
    return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: While adding that model data into ArrayList check, If that model does not contain into ArrayList then add the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by putting the selected items on `ArrayList<>`

and make  the validations like this:

```
 if (position2 != 0) {
                vio_val = String.valueOf(spinner_violation.getSelectedItem());

                if (!violationHolder.contains(vio_val)) {
                    adapter = new ViolationAdapter(getContext(), generateData());
                    violationHolder.add(vio_val);

                    lv_inspector_violation.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Duplicate Violation.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your help